# JMeter - Exception when using Beanshell as JSR223 Sampler with file

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I have a file with simple JSR223 code:

```
log.info("Hello JSR223")
```

When I choose Beanshell as language in JSR223 Sampler I get the following exception:

```
2018-06-21 10:32:28,148 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: In file: eval stream Encountered "<EOF>" at line 2, column 24.
 in eval stream at line number 2
javax.script.ScriptException: In file: eval stream Encountered "<EOF>" at line 2, column 24.
 in eval stream at line number 2
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:82) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:52) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:199) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

Same code work without file by adding to Script field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [Beanshell](http://beanshell.org/) you need to stick to [Java SE 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/overview-137139.html) syntax to wit your statement needs to end with semicolon, amend it to look like:

```
log.info("Hello JSR223");
//                      ^ this is uber important
```

and your script should start working as expected.

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so I would suggest keeping "Language" as `groovy`, in this case the semicolon is not necessary.